# What is the color group name in the UI image?

Tags: color

I am actually developer not a graphic designer.
I want to know these color groups name. They look like ocean colors but there has to be an official graphic design name. What is the color group name for that?
https://tr.pinterest.com/pin/565412928200221463/

And I don't know "color group name" is the true definition anyway.

Thank you.

Comment: Why would it have a name? You could just call it Bob. Its not entirely practical to call all possible color ranges by names. But yes it can probably be described as cold colored (Except not all of your images are just cool colors)

Comment: I am not a designer, maybe you designers have special names when you talk to eachother about colors. I thought maybe they have a name like pastel colors or something else but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Im not a designer, but overall its best not to get into jargon when designing as the purpose of design is to talk to an audience, in this case your client. If your client does not understand your jargon then its useless. Int is a whole other ballgame if i need to be able to locate for example fonts. But colors are a complex continuum so its not entirely possible to describe all possible color sets with meaningful names [see this post on the fact that there is no boundary for green](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/76184/what-are-the-shades-of-green/76186#76186).

Comment: What are we even supposed to look for on that pinterest page?

Answer (score 3):

In general not all ranges have names even the ones that do are very diffuse. But as of a rule of thumbs there are characterizations for colors. So colors have a temperature and you can differentiate between warm or cool colors. In this case you can find a bunch of **cool gradients*** by doing a [image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=cool+color+gradients&client=firefox-b&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE097ji83OAhUFJJoKHRTXC60QsAQIJA&biw=1989&bih=1171&dpr=0.8) on google. But as you can see there are quite many cool color ranges. We can also call colors saturated or unsaturated, muddy or clear and so on.

One problem is that we as humans can not really [distinguish color names](https://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/), so while its possible to give hundreds or even thousands of names to colors. People wont actually agree with each others on these points. So for example while you and i would agree there is such colors as pastels, we do not agree where pastels begin and where they cease to be pastel colored.

* In this case it does not really help that we call cold things cool as well as awesome, or swell. So a warm gradient might be awesome and somebody would call that cool. That is people for you.

Comment: Swell, in my mind, only relates to [waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swell_(ocean)). Damn language.

Comment: I've never thought that way. I try to improve the design part of me. This way to define colors make sense right now. You show me a good way. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Only a spectrometer knows for sure.